# How do you enable SSL for PHP cURL on Linux?

Tags: php, curl

That's all there is to my question: how do you enable SSL for PHP cURL on Linux (specifically Ubuntu)? I'm not finding the answer by Googling it.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?  If it is really old, then you may have to do a lot of recompiling, if it is recent, then as soon as you install the php curl module it should just work(tm).

Comment: Version 11 --------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get install php5-curl` does the trick.

Comment: All right, I guess I already had it enabled. I'm having a certain problem and I guess it's not due to SSL not being enabled.